# Unable to center textfield on iPhone app

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm new to IOS development and am hitting my first hurdle.  In Xcode 7.1, I've only put a single textfield on the main storyboard.  I expanded the width of the textfield to be the entire width of the storyboard.  When I run the application, it opens up on my iPhone without problem.  I also have version 5s of iPhone selected in the xCode editor, matching the version that I own.  The issue I have is that the textfield runs off of the right of the iPhone screen in the running application on the iPhone.  Any direction is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What trailing edge constraint have you set on the text field?

Comment: @Paulw11 it is because he didn't set any constraint.

Comment: Thank you Paulw11 and ozgur, your comments led me to fixing it.  I Googled and found this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/chapters/pin-constraints.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll wager you haven't set constraints. The "quick and dirty" way to do this would be to go to the bottom and click the "Tie Fighter" looking icon w/ a triangle in the center. Click "Reset to Suggested Constraints" or "Add Missing Constraints".[image]

You'll notice there are two sets of options:
* selected views (if you only selected the UITextField)
* all views in container (if you want Autolayout to apply constraints to everything in the view).

Alternatively, you could control click from your textfield and drag to the edge (left would be leading, right would be trailing, top would be vertical spacing to top layout guide).